# Converting Risk Ratios to Odds Ratio in case-crossover trial for meta-analysis

Tags: ratio, odds, risk

I am doing a meta-analyss of case crossover & time series studies.
so the problem is some studies have reported the RRs, & I need ORs. The data I have is not enough which is

-Total sample size (there is no separate N for cases/controls)

-Risk ratio

Is there anyway I can calcualte the RR from just these 2 parameters?

Thank you in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

If the event is very rare then the relative risk (risk ratio) *approximates* the odds ratio quite well by appealing to the central limit theorem, but otherwise, then, unfortunately, I don't believe you can achieve what you want. What you need are the number for a 2x2 contingency table:

```
|               | Disease (Outcome) | No Disease |
|---------------|-------------------|------------|
| Exposed       | a                 | b          |
| Not Exposed   | c                 | d          |
```

The odds ratio (OR) is calculated thus:
$$
OR = \frac{a/b}{c/d} = \frac{ad}{bc}
$$

Comment: If a case-crossover analysis makes sense then the event probably is rare enough for the approximation to work

Comment: And the approximation has nothing to do with the central limit theorem.  It's also useful to estimate odds ratios directly and then convert to covariate-specific risk ratios as explained [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/lrm#odds-ratio-risk-ratio-and-risk-difference).  This approach recognizes that odds ratios are less likely to need interaction terms than risk ratios, because ORs don't have a restricted range.